# What are the three possible DAGs with two vertices

Tags: graph-theory

This is a very elementary question:  I am not sure I understand the definition of a DAG correctly; I read on Wikipedia that there are three possible DAGs with 2 vertices. I can see 
A->B and B->A, but what is the third one?

I tried to look this up for quite a while, but could not find it. It seems that all the vertices of a graph need to be connected to at least one other vertex, so that rules out A and B without an edge between them. But again, what is the third one then?

Comment: "It seems that all the vertices of a graph need to be connected to at least one other vertex."  Why do you say this?  There's no such requirement.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure, but I remember reading that there had to be some path between every vertex. If that is not the case, then I guess the answer is that the third DAG is two vertices without a connection.

Comment: That is the third DAG.  There's even a name for a vertex with no neighbor: a "isolated vertex."